# How to pass column to arrange() and mutate()

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like a function that uses `dplyr` and looks something like `AddPercentColumns()` below.

```r
AddPercentColumns <- function(df, col) {
    # Sorts and adds "Percent" and "Cumulative Percent" columns to a data.frame.
    #
    # Args:
    #   df: data frame
    #   col: column symbol
    #
    # Returns:
    #   Data frame sorted by "col" with new "Percent" and "Cumulative Percent" columns.

    df %>%
        arrange(desc(col)) %>%
        mutate(Percent = col / sum(col) * 100) %>% 
        mutate(Cumulative = cumsum(Percent))
}
```

However, I'm having trouble wrapping my head around how to work-around NSE. I could potentially pass in a column name string and use `arrange_()` and `mutate_()`, but then I'm not sure what to do about `desc()`, `sum()` and `cumsum()`.

How should this function be written using `dplyr`?

Comment: Thanks, Gregor! Posting something I threw together below...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on suggestions from Konrad, I'm posting another solution as it evolves. :)

```r
AddPercentColumns <- function(df, col) {
    # Sorts data.frame and adds "Percent" and "Cumulative Percent" columns.
    #
    # Args:
    #   df: data frame
    #   col: unevaluated column symbol e.g. substitute(col)
    #
    # Returns:
    #   Data frame sorted by "col" with new "Percent" and "Cumulative Percent" columns.

    df %>%
        arrange_(bquote(desc(.(col)))) %>%
        mutate_(Percent = bquote(.(col) / sum(.(col)) * 100)) %>% 
        mutate(Cumulative = cumsum(Percent))
}
```

Definitely cleaner, more debuggable and readable.

Comment: Deleted my earlier comments, this is a much better solution. Is it using `plyr::"."`?

Comment: I'm guessing no. bquote() is from base and the bquote help specifically refers to .(). Also, I have plyr "loaded via a namespace (and not attached)."

Answer (score 0):

I find `sprintf()` a little bit easier to read than `paste()`. The function below seems like it'd be a lot of fun to debug, but it gets the job done.

```r
AddPercentColumn <- function(df, col) {
    # Sorts data.frame and adds "Percent" and "Cumulative Percent" columns.
    #
    # Args:
    #   df: data frame
    #   col: column name string
    #
    # Returns:
    #   Data frame sorted by "col" with new "Percent" and "Cumulative Percent" columns.

    df %>%
        arrange_(sprintf("desc(%s)", col)) %>%
        mutate_(Percent = sprintf("%s / sum(%s) * 100", col, col)) %>% 
        mutate_(Cumulative = "cumsum(Percent)")
}
```

Not super clean though...

Comment: There’s no need to use `mutate_` in the last line, `mutate` works just fine. In addition, I would really object to the use of strings here in any project in which I were to collaborate. It works, but it’s a terrible abuse of the type system. Use expressions and/or `lazyeval` here. In fact, I think it’s a mistake on the part of dplyr that it even accepts this code.

Comment: Just to add to that, the first part of the expression in a non-string version could look as follows: `arrange_(bquote(desc(.(col))))` — assuming we captured the unevaluated column name beforehand: `col = substitute(col)`. The second part of the pipeline follows by equivalence.